# After installing modele program is still not running

Tags: python, pip

Am importing opcua in my python file:

```
from opcua import Client
```

before i ran `python -m pip install opcua` and it was succesfully installed
but it is still not resolved after i ran the file

am using python 3.10.4 and i upgraded pip to latest version

Answer (score 0):

You should also install the cryptography module:
`pip install cryptography`
Opcua depends on it. Once installed it should work.